# Exponential transition

Tags: exponential-function

I have a general formula to calculate temperature gradient. It is quite old and there are better ways of doing it but I need to do it this way.
I have a description of a formula for the transition between day and night that says "The transition from day to night is to be done exponentially with a time constant of 2 hours".
I don't know how to accomplish this but could it be somehow along the lines of
$$ \frac{dT}{dz}(t_2)_{exp} = ln((e^{\frac{dT}{dz}(t_2)}+e^{\frac{\frac{dT}{dz}(t_1)_{exp}}{(\tau/dt-1)}}+e^{\frac{\frac{dT}{dz}(t_0)_{exp}}{(\tau/dt-2)}})/3) $$
where
$ \frac{dT}{dz}(t_2) $
is the "raw" temperature gradient calculated with the formula at second hour, and $ \frac{dT}{dz}(t_2)_{exp} $ is the exponentially averaged gradient at the second hour, $ dt $ is the time step (1 hour) and $ \tau $ is the time constant (2 hours). I  ​know this formula doesn't work ... so I need some help or tips.. Anything is most welcome :)

The resulting "raw" values form the general formula are as follows:
(sun sets right before 20 hours, in the 19th hour)
| Hour | Temp. grad (raw formula) | Temp. grad exp |
| ---- | -----------| ----------- |
| 16   | -0.060     | resulting
| 17   | -0.060      | values |
| 18   | -0.010      | should |
| 19   |  0.025      | go |
| 20   |  0.025      | here|
| 21   |  0.025      |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a google search for expnential *smoothing* did the trick. From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing)

$$ \frac{dT}{dz}(t_2)_{exp} = \alpha*\frac{dT}{dz}(t_2) +(1-\alpha)* \frac{dT}{dz}(t_2)$$

where
$$ \alpha = 1-e^{^-dt/\tau} $$

and $dt$ and $\tau$ are described in the question.